# register_activation_hook for multiple functions

Tags: functions, activation

I have created a plugin where I want to call two different functions on activation.

Is there a best way to do this?

Should I use `register_activation_hook` twice? As in:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'function_1' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'function_1' );
```

Or call the two functions from within an activation function, as in:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_activation_function' );
function my_activation_function () {

    function_1();
    function_2();

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: adding multiple instances of `register_activation_hook` does work - though it may not be the *right way* to do it.

Answer (score 3):

My approach to this would be to have a `start_activation()` method that calls the other methods.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'my_plugin_loader', 'start_activation' ) );

class my_plugin_loader {
    function start_activation() {
        $this->func1(); // or self::func1();
        $this->func2(); //    self::func2(); for static methods
     }
     function func1() {
         // do stuff
     }
     function func2() {
         // do other stuff
     }
 }
```

I'm not saying it is the "right" way, just how I would approach it.

Comment: This is what I've gone for, though using the procedural way in my original post. It works fine. Thanks for the *method/OOP* variant!